# PHP can't fopen remote file

Tags: php, fopen

I'm making a script to open remote file (ftp) and edit it with fopen and fwrite.I have problem while connecting to ftp.I made this code

```
     $handle =        fopen("ftp://".$ftp['username'].":".$ftp['password']."@".$ftp['server']."/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/configs/users.ini", "w") or die("ftp error");
fwrite($handle,$text."\n") or die('err2.');
```

al variables are set.I tried with ftp://... in web page and it works.allow_url_fopen is On...
It just says "ftp error"

Comment: Why not use the ftp functions? http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php You'll at least get much better error handling.  I realize there's useful abstraction to being able to write to a file handle, but the ftp functions are so much clearer.

Comment: Note that you can't **edit** files with the `ftp://` wrapper, only create new files/completely overwrite existing files. See [ftp:// Wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) for what you can do with the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ftp://` handler [only allows creating new files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) with `fopen("ftp://...", "w");`.

If the file already exists you can only write to it if you open it with overwriting set, i.e mode `w+`.