# Open FTP file Issue

Tags: php, ftp, fopen

I am trying to open ftp file using below lines,

```
 $con = ftp_connect(myhost);
                if (!$con) {
                throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
                }   
    $loggedIn = ftp_login($con,  'user',  'pass');
    if ($loggedIn) {
                    if(ftp_get($con, test.csv, "ftp://myhost/test.csv", FTP_ASCII))
                       echo 'in';
                    else 
                       echo 'out';
                   }
```

Then I am getting error

> ftp_get(): File not found

but if I ran ftp path in browser it fetches file correctly.

can anyone guide me in correct path ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of `fopen()`, try using [`ftp_get()`](http://php.net/ftp_get) or [`ftp_fget()`](http://php.net/ftp_fget). (*You can read about why `fopen` won't work the majority of the time with `ftp://` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10552592/2518525)*)

Comment: i will try this and let you know

Comment: when i use ftp_get(), i got this  error "ftp_get(): File not found"

Comment: Did you follow the example on the PHPDocs page?

Comment: FTP is an insecure protocol. The credentials are passed in clear text to the server and can be sniffed. Consider using SFTP or another more secure solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to go with `ftp_get()`:

```
$con = ftp_connect(myhost);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($con, 'file_to_save_to.csv', 'test.csv', FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
```

---

As [*@Gordon stated in the comments*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668031/open-ftp-file-issue?noredirect=1#comment51280422_31668031):

> FTP is an insecure protocol. The credentials are passed in clear text
>   to the server and can be sniffed. Consider using SFTP or another more
>   secure solution.

Comment: yes, "ftp://myhost/test.csv", this url works in browser

Comment: Wrap that `test.csv` in quotes - `'test.csv'`, otherwise it's assumed as a constant (**So make it look like this:** `ftp_get($con, 'test.csv', "test.csv", FTP_ASCII)`). Also, could you try `file_get_contents()` @AyyanarG

Comment: its working now i have used ""ftp://myhost/test.csv"" as remote dir path, if i remove that and give just "test.csv" its working